# Where is the materials tab?

Tags: materials, interface

I can't find the materials tab. I have tried blender tutorials but they already have the tabs. I just have these 5 tabs:

[image: blender properties]

Answer (score 4):

Here is the materials tab:
[image]

Note:
If you can't see it there, hover over the tabs and scroll with the Middle Mouse Button.

Also be sure that you have a mesh selected, if you don't blender will not show the materials tab.

Almost any video tutorial should show you were that is, so I'd recommend you research some more.

Comment: Also if there is no active object, you have only 5 tabs. So just select a mesh and the material tabs will appear.

Comment: that you sooo much

Comment: @user4935 You can show your appreciation by accepting my answer. That is done by clicking the check mark outline.